# disable default Scroll to top in web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, scroll

I'm new to React and Web.
I am trying to load some chats data, whenever I add some chats to the top of the chat list, automatically chats container scrolled to the top of chats, I mean first chat in term of creating time.
how to disable this scrolling behavior?
I also tried a library called reverse-infinite-search.

useChatLoad.ts

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios, {Canceler} from "axios";
import {API_KEY, BASE_SANGRIA_URL} from "../apis/BaseApi";
import {Message} from "../models/Message";

export default function useChat(visitorId: string, fetchBeforeTimestampMillis: number, scrollToBottom: () => void) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [chats, setChats] = useState<Message[]>([]);
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState<boolean>(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        setChats([]);
    }, [visitorId]);


    const onNewMessageReceived = (m: Message) => {
        setChats([...chats, m]);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(false);
        let canceler: Canceler;
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL,
            data: {userId: visitorId, fetchBeforeTimestampMillis: fetchBeforeTimestampMillis},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', "API-KEY": API_KEY},
            cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => canceler = c)
        }).then(res => {
            console.log("fetch called")
            if (res.status != 200 || res.data.error != null) {
                console.log(res.status + "   " + res.data.error);
                setError(true);
                return;
            }

            let messages: Message[] = res.data.messages;
            messages = messages.reverse();

            if (chats.length == 0 && messages.length != 0)
                scrollToBottom()

            setChats(prevChats => {
                return [...messages, ...prevChats]
            })

            setHasMore(res.data.messages.length > 0);
            setLoading(false);
        }).catch(e => {
            if (axios.isCancel(e)) return;
            console.log("l41 useChatLoad ", e);
            setError(true);
        })
    }, [visitorId, fetchBeforeTimestampMillis])
    return {loading, error, chats, hasMore, onNewMessageReceived};
}
```

ChatContent.tsx

```
import React, {createRef, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import styles from './ChatContent.module.css';
import ChatItem from "../chat-item/ChatItem";
import {Message} from "../../models/Message";
import InputField from "../input-field/InputField";
import useChatsLoad from "../../custom-hooks/useChasLoad";
import InfiniteScrollReverse from "../inf-scroll/InfiniteScrollReverse";
import {OtherOperatorMessagePayload, Sangria, VisitorMessagePayload} from "../../sangria/Sangria";
import {isEmptyText} from "../../tools/Tools";

interface Props {
    isOnline: boolean
    visitorId: string,
    onOperatorMessageReceived: (m: OtherOperatorMessagePayload) => void
    onCustomerMessageReceived: (m: VisitorMessagePayload) => void
}


const ChatContent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {

    const [msg, setMsg] = useState<string>("");
    const [fetchBeforeTimeStamp, setFetchBeforeTimeStamp] = useState<number>(Date.now());
    const [sangria, setSangria] = useState<Sangria>();
    const messagesEndRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    function scrollToBottom() {
        console.log("scroll to bottom called")
          messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "auto"})
    }


    const {
        chats,
        hasMore,
        loading,
        error,
        onNewMessageReceived
    } = useChatsLoad(props.visitorId, fetchBeforeTimeStamp, scrollToBottom);


    useEffect(() => {
        let sg = new Sangria();

        sg.setReceiveMessageFromOtherOperatorCallback(data => {
            props.onOperatorMessageReceived(data);

            if (data.message.customerId != props.visitorId) return;

            let newMessage: Message = {
                meta: data.message.meta,
                messageType: data.message.messageType,
                body: data.message.body,
                id: data.message.id,
                createdAt: data.message.createdAt,
                sender: data.sender
            }

            onNewMessageReceived(newMessage);

        });

        sg.setVisitorTypingCallback(d => {

        })

        sg.setReceiveMessageFromVisitorCallback(data => {
            props.onCustomerMessageReceived(data);

            if (data.customerId != props.visitorId) return;

            let newMessage: Message = {
                sender: data.sender,
                createdAt: data.createdAt,
                id: data.id,
                body: data.body,
                messageType: data.messageType,
                meta: data.meta,
            }
            onNewMessageReceived(newMessage);
        })


        setSangria(sg);
    }, [])


    // const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
    //
    // const firstChatItemElement = useCallback(node => {
    //     if (loading) return;
    //
    //     if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
    //
    //     observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    //         if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
    //             updateFetchBeforeTimeStamp();
    //         }
    //     })
    //     if (node) observer.current?.observe(node);
    // }, [loading, hasMore])
    //

    function sendMessage() {

        if (isEmptyText(props.visitorId)) {
            setMsg("");
            return;
        }


        sangria?.sendMessage("text", msg, "", props.visitorId);
        setMsg("")
    }

    function sendOperatorTypingEvent() {
        if (isEmptyText(props.visitorId)) {
            return;
        }
        sangria?.sentOperatorTypingEvent(props.visitorId);
    }


    function sendImage() {
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        updateFetchBeforeTimeStamp();
    },[chats.length])

    function updateFetchBeforeTimeStamp() {
        console.log("fetch beforeTimeStamp called")
        if (chats.length == 0)
            setFetchBeforeTimeStamp(Date.now());
        else
            setFetchBeforeTimeStamp(chats[0].createdAt);
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.main__chatcontent}>
            <div className={styles.content__header}>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.content__body}>
                <InfiniteScrollReverse className={styles.chat_items} loadMore={() => {
                    updateFetchBeforeTimeStamp()
                }} hasMore={hasMore} isLoading={loading}  loadArea={30}>
                    {chats.map((itm, index) => {
                        return (<ChatItem key={itm.id} message={itm} ref={index == 0 ? null : null}/>)
                    })}
                    <div key="end" ref={messagesEndRef}/>
                </InfiniteScrollReverse>
                {/*<div className={styles.chat_items}>*/}
                {/*  */}
                {/*</div>*/}
            </div>
            <InputField onAttach={sendImage} onSend={sendMessage} onTextChanged={e => {
                setMsg(e.target.value);
                sendOperatorTypingEvent()
            }} text={msg}/>
        </div>
    )
}


export default ChatContent;
```

InfiniteScrollReverse.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function InfiniteScrollReverse({ className, isLoading, hasMore, loadArea, loadMore, children }) {
    const infiniteRef = useRef();

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

    // Reset default page, if children equals to 0
    useEffect(() => {
        if (children.length === 0) {
            setCurrentPage(1);
        }
    }, [children.length]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect in inf -scroll called")
        let { current: scrollContainer } = infiniteRef;
        function onScroll() {
            // Handle scroll direction
            console.log(scrollContainer.scrollTop," $$$")
            if (scrollContainer.scrollTop > scrollPosition) {
                // Scroll bottom
            } else {
                // Check load more scroll area
                if (scrollContainer.scrollTop <= loadArea && !isLoading) {
                    // Check for available data
                    if (hasMore) {
                        // Run data fetching
                        const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
                        setCurrentPage(nextPage);
                        loadMore(nextPage);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Save event scroll position
            setScrollPosition(scrollContainer.scrollTop);
        }

        scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
        return () => {
            scrollContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
        };
    }, [currentPage, hasMore, isLoading, loadArea, loadMore, scrollPosition]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let { current: scrollContainer } = infiniteRef;
        if (children.length) {
            // Get available top scroll
            const availableScroll = scrollContainer.scrollHeight - scrollContainer.clientHeight;
            // Get motion for first page
            if (currentPage === 1) {
                // Move data to bottom for getting load more area
                if (availableScroll >= 0) {
                    scrollContainer.scrollTop = availableScroll;
                }
            } else {
                // Add scroll area for other pages
                if (hasMore) {
                    scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.clientHeight;
                }
            }
        }
    }, [children.length, currentPage, hasMore]);

    return (
        <div className={className} ref={infiniteRef}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

InfiniteScrollReverse.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.array,
    hasMore: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    loadMore: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    loadArea: PropTypes.number,
};

InfiniteScrollReverse.defaultProps = {
    className: "InfiniteScrollReverse",
    children: [],
    loadArea: 30,
};

export default InfiniteScrollReverse;
```

Comment: Hi there, please include some code that shows what is going on.

Comment: Hi man, I added some codes,